# Using webform-form-[nid].tpl.php to change default template

Tags: theming, webforms

On drupal 7, using webform 7.x-4.11, I am trying to modify the template of a specific webform.

So, in /web/themes/bartik/templates (I am using bartik theme) I created a file named webform-form-23.tpl.php

As "23" is the nid of my webform. But the template is not applying at all...

If a create a file webform-form.tpl.php it is well applying to all my webforms...

This is not a matter of caches as it is well applying when using a file named "webform-form.tpl.php" (with no ID) and despite of that the cache has been cleared at every changes.

Can someone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a clear cache in `admin/config/development/performance`?

Or have you looked if in the template there is a error in the code? To verify this you can try to copy all code of "webform-form.tpl.php" in your "webform-form-23.tpl.php" and at the top of the code, before the first TEST!!! , refresh the cache and look if TEST!!! is displayed. If you display TEST!!! in your previous code there is an error.

Comment: Sure! And the template is changing with no problems with a file with no ID (webform-form.tpl.php)

Comment: @Fumble : good to know, I suggest you ADD that to your actual question also ...

Comment: Have you looked if in the template there is a error in the code? Try to copy all code of "webform-form.tpl.php"  in your "webform-form-23.tpl.php"  and at the top of the code, before the first `<?php` , add `<h1>TEST!!!</H1>` , refresh the cache and look if TEST!!! is displayed.

Comment: obviously it was an issue in the code inside the tpl file, it is working well now... Tank you!